# Ember Serializer works for Mirage but not with real data

Tags: json, ember.js, adapter, serialization

I am new to Ember and is trying to create a small application using version beta 2.3.0.

Provided a country and zipcode, I am trying to get the city and zipcode. 
With Mirage and a custom serializer (I am using the same format as of real json) my code works perfectly.

However, with the real API, the Promise remains in Pending state. There is no error in console. 
And the logs in my serializer does not display when using real service indicating that the serializer is not executing. 
Has anyone faced a similar issue before. Please help.

In my controller, I am finding the record as:

```
this.store.find('address', zipcode).then(
                function(address) {
                    console.log("Hello Got Address");
});
```

My adapters/application.js :

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
 host: 'http://real_url_here',

 pathForType: function(type) {
      return '';
}});
```

The JSONAPISerialier is overriden in serializers/application.js as:

```
export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({

normalizeResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {

.......... // Code goes here
}});
```

In my mirage/config.js,  I am returning sample json for 2 zipcodes and at the end I have added:

```
this.passthrough('http://real_url_here/**');
```

to invoke real service for other zipcodes

Comment: please add some example code.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer finally :).

I had to disable the mirage in development :

To disable in development,

```
// config/environment.js
...
if (environment === 'development') {
      ENV['ember-cli-mirage'] = {
      enabled: false
}}
```